# Упростить код до 5 строк

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Можно ли упростить этот код до 5 строк (вопрос из собеседования на позицию senior javascript developer)?:

```js
function func(s, a, b)
{
   var match_empty=/^$/ ;
   if (s.match(match_empty))
   {
       return -1;
   }
   else
   {
       var i=s.length-1;
       var aIndex=-1;
       var bIndex=-1;

       while ((aIndex==-1) && (bIndex==-1) && (i>=0))
       {
           if (s.substring(i, i+1) == a)
               aIndex=i;
        if (s.substring(i, i+1) == b)
               bIndex=i;
        i--;
       }

       if (aIndex != -1)
       {
           if (bIndex == -1)
               return aIndex;
        else
               return Math.max(aIndex, bIndex);
       }
       else
       {
           if (bIndex != -1)
               return bIndex;       
      else
               return -1;
       }
   }
};
```

Comment: можно, см. [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Comment: в принципе переносы в яваскрипте не значимы, поэтому любой код можно записать в одну строку

Comment: @Grundy в вопросе слово "упростить", а Вы сейчас говорите про "сократить". Можно ли считать минифицированный код упрощённым? Я думаю, что однозначно нет.

Comment: @NewDevelop, все зависит от определения упрощенности

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Навскидку, вроде бы, вот так можно «упростить»:

```
function func(s, a, b)
{
    return Math.max( s.lastIndexOf(a), s.lastIndexOf(b));
}
```

Но это не правильно обработает случаи с пустыми строками в `a` или `b`. Поэтому:

**upd.** с тестами

```js
function funcSergiks(s, a, b) {
  return Math.max(
    (a.length ? s.lastIndexOf(a) : -1), (b.length ? s.lastIndexOf(b) : -1)
  )
}

// ---------------------------------------

function func(s, a, b) {
  var match_empty = /^$/;
  if (s.match(match_empty)) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    var i = s.length - 1;
    var aIndex = -1;
    var bIndex = -1;
    while ((aIndex == -1) && (bIndex == -1) && (i >= 0)) {
      if (s.substring(i, i + 1) == a) aIndex = i;
      if (s.substring(i, i + 1) == b) bIndex = i;
      i--;
    }
    if (aIndex != -1) {
      if (bIndex == -1) return aIndex;
      else return Math.max(aIndex, bIndex);
    } else {
      if (bIndex != -1) return bIndex;
      else return -1;
    }
  }
};

var tests = [
  [
    ['google', 'g', 'o'], 3
  ],
  [
    ['aba', 'a', 'b'], 2
  ],
  [
    ['', 'g', 'o'], -1
  ],
  [
    ['google', 'x', 'o'], 2
  ],
  [
    ['aba', '', ''], -1
  ],
  [
    ['aba', 'a', ''], 2
  ],
  [
    ['aba', '', 'b'], 1
  ],
  [
    ['aba', 'a', 'b'], 2
  ],
];

tests.forEach(test => {
  var a = func.apply(this, test[0]);
  var b = funcSergiks.apply(this, test[0]);
  console.log(a == b && b == test[1] ? "PASSED" : "FAILED", JSON.stringify(test), a, b);
});
```

Comment: а что тут происходит поясните с двух словах пожалуйста?

Comment: @Sergiks спасибо за идею, принято.

Comment: @stas0k, возвращается максимальное значение из индексов a и b в строке s

Comment: @stas0k передаётся три строки. В первой, если она ненулевая, ищуются вхождения второй и третьей справа налево и запоминаются позиции последних найденных (значит, самых левых). Если найдены вхождения обеих строк, возращается позиция той, что правее. Если только одной, то её. Если ни одной, -1.

Comment: @Sergiks, мне кажется упрощение не совсем получилось. В примере цикл заканчивается как только найдет хотя бы одну из переменных, и сразу выходит. То есть вариант, когда найдутся два индекса может быть только если `a===b`, и тогда все равно что возвращать, и в итоге все-таки `lastIndexOf` нужен

Comment: @Sergiks А почему не `lastIndexOf()` а просто `indexOf()`. В задаче поиск начинается c конца `var i=s.length-1;`

Comment: Пример при котором результаты функций не совпадают: функция из ответа `func('aba','a','b')` -> 1, функция из вопроса `func('aba','a','b')` -> 2

Comment: @Grundy, да, я зря дёргался, сначала всё правильно написал, `lastIndexOf()`

Comment: @Sergiks, на самом деле и сейчас поведение отличается :-) я у себя в ответе добавил несколько проверок :)

Comment: @Grundy, ок, заморочился на проверки и тесты )

Comment: @Sergiks, ну вот :-) другое дело

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос в принципе не корректен, так как в яваскрипте не значимы отступы и переносы строк, любую программу можно записать в одну строку, чем собственно и пользуются различные минификаторы.

Для *упрощения* кода, сначала нужно определить, что именно делает данный код.

1. при пустой строке возвращается -1
2. в цикле ищется какой-то индекс
3. возвращается найденный индекс.

Стоит подробнее остановиться на цикле:

1. условия выхода: `(aIndex==-1) && (bIndex==-1) && (i>=0)` их можно интерпретировать как - пока не найден любой из элементов, либо пока не кончилась строка
2. тело цикла

   ```
   while ((aIndex==-1) && (bIndex==-1) && (i>=0))
   {
       if (s.substring(i, i+1) == a)
           aIndex=i;
       if (s.substring(i, i+1) == b)
           bIndex=i;
       i--;
   }
   ```

   Тут стоит обратить внимание на определение индекса.

   ```
    if (s.substring(i, i+1) == b)
   ```

   записываем, что элемент найден по текущему индексу, если подстрока из одного символа, начиная с текущего равна переданному элементу.

   Это показывает, что, во-первых, параметры должны быть одним символом, во-вторых, параметры пустые строки не будут найдены, то есть нужно будет возвращать -1.

Если подвести итог: функция возвращает -1, если строка пустая, либо если оба искомых параметра пустые строки, если строка не пустая и хотя бы один из параметров не пустая строка, то возвращается максимальный индекс из параметров

```js
function func(s, a, b) {
  if (s == '' || (a == '' && b == '')) return -1;
  for (var i = s.length; --i >= 0;)
    if (s[i] == a || s[i] == b) return i;
};

console.log('func', func('aba', 'a', 'b'));
console.log('func', func('aba', '', ''));
console.log('func', func('aba', '', 'b'));
console.log('func', func('aba', 'a', ''));

function funcSrc(s, a, b) {
  var match_empty = /^$/;
  if (s.match(match_empty)) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    var i = s.length - 1;
    var aIndex = -1;
    var bIndex = -1;

    while ((aIndex == -1) && (bIndex == -1) && (i >= 0)) {
      if (s.substring(i, i + 1) == a)
        aIndex = i;
      if (s.substring(i, i + 1) == b)
        bIndex = i;
      i--;
    }

    if (aIndex != -1) {
      if (bIndex == -1)
        return aIndex;
      else
        return Math.max(aIndex, bIndex);
    } else {
      if (bIndex != -1)
        return bIndex;
      else
        return -1;
    }
  }
};

console.log('funcSrc', funcSrc('aba', 'a', 'b'));
console.log('funcSrc', funcSrc('aba', '', ''));
console.log('funcSrc', funcSrc('aba', '', 'b'));
console.log('funcSrc', funcSrc('aba', 'a', ''));


function funcIndexOf(s, a, b) {
  return Math.max(s.indexOf(a), s.indexOf(b));
}

console.log('funcIndexOf', funcIndexOf('aba', 'a', 'b'));
console.log('funcIndexOf', funcIndexOf('aba', '', ''));
console.log('funcIndexOf', funcIndexOf('aba', '', 'b'));
console.log('funcIndexOf', funcIndexOf('aba', 'a', ''));

function funcLastIndexOf(s, a, b) {
  return Math.max(s.lastIndexOf(a), s.lastIndexOf(b));
}

console.log('funcLastIndexOf', funcLastIndexOf('aba', 'a', 'b'));
console.log('funcLastIndexOf', funcLastIndexOf('aba', '', ''));
console.log('funcLastIndexOf', funcLastIndexOf('aba', '', 'b'));
console.log('funcLastIndexOf', funcLastIndexOf('aba', 'a', ''));
```

Comment: о корректности вопроса это уже не ко мне, такой был на собеседовании, предложенный одному из разработчиков )))

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov, добавил описание в вопрос, кстати возможно, что какие-то граничные значения все-таки не учел и результаты все еще могут отличаться от исходной функции.

Comment: огромное спасибо за помощь ;-))